# ng-repeat | filter, How do I use the new this.$index or key from JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, filter, indexing, key, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I filter ng-repeat, this.$index and key both change to reflect the objects position in the filtered array.

The problem is that I only see the unfiltered array from the JavaScript so this.$index and key  are giving an unexpected result.

HTML:

```
<section ng-repeat="( key, place ) in places | filter: ({ name : placeName })" >

<button ng-click='myFunc( this.$index )'>Pick {{place.name}}</button> <!-- same issue with key -->
<section>
```

Javascript:

```
myFunc(key){
console.log( $scope.places[key] ); 
}
```

I can loop over the array and find $id or my own identifier but that seems wasteful when all I need is an index that I can pass on to my function which is looking at the unfiltered array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing in the index, pass in the actual object:

```
<section ng-repeat="( key, place ) in places | filter: ({ name : placeName })" >

<button ng-click='myFunc( place )'>Pick {{place.name}}</button> 
<!-- same issue with key -->
<section>
```

Then in your JavaScript

```
$scope.myFunc(place){
    console.log( place ); 
}
```

This will make testing the myFunc method even easier since you are supplying the object in which you will be acting upon.